# Django how to update a record rather than raise error on duplicate id

Tags: django, django-models

I guess what I need to do it overwrite my model's `save` method but do correct me if I'm wrong/have better suggestion.

This is what my model looks like:

```
class MergingModel(models.Model):
   some_field = models.TextField()
```

And this is the unit test that I want to pass:

```
  class MergingModelTests(TestCase):
      def test_duplicates_are_overwriten(self):
          MergingModel.create(id=1)
          MergingModel.create(id=1, some_field="abc")

          self.assertEquals(MergingModel.objects.count(),1)
          self.assetEquals(MergingModel.objects.get(id=1).some_field,"abc")
```

I tried overwriting `save` method to check if record with `id=x` exists but that raised recursion errors, my code for save method looked like:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if MergingModel.objects.filter(id__exact=self.id):
       original = MergingModel.objects.get(id=self.id)
       original.some_field = self.some_field 
       original.save()
    else:
       super().save( *args, **kwargs)
```

Then I tried overwriting `create` but I get error:

> Key (id)=(ID1) already exists

So I'm not really sure what to do anymore.

Comment: Use `update_or_create`, instead of `create`.

Comment: @sgp667 Will **`id`** pass everytime ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I wasn't aware of that method I've been trying to code that behavior myself, that gives me one more option to try. @JPG, yes `id` will always be available.

Comment: @sgp667: well I would really advice to *avoid* writing logic in the `.save(..)` since the Django ORM does *not* always calls `.save()`: there are ways to *bypass* `.save(..)` like `Model.objects.update(..)`, etc.